# Reusing previously defined data types inside loop

Tags: c++

I'm trying to do the following:

ask the user for a name, then ask the user for values (which will be used to construct a collection of vectors), then print out various combinations of the values, then do it all over again.

My problem is that after the first loop and after asking for the name again I get a "segmentation fault (core dump)" error message. I'm assuming this has to do with the vectors which were constructed/defined in the first loop. So, I'm wondering if there is any way to clear these objects after each loop. That is, what I'd like is:

```
Do {
     ask user for name 
     ask user for values
     create vectors from these values
     print off certain elements of the vectors
     reset/delete name, values, vectors so that I can run the loop again as if it's the first time
} while(condition);
```

If you can point me towards any useful references that would be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Clear a `std::vector` instance `vec` with `vec.clear();`

Comment: @jonesy, why do you need to reset/clear the vector? I don't think vector is the right class to use.

Comment: what code did segmentation fault? post it, or the question will not be understood

Comment: If you want us to spot errors in your code, we have to *see the code*. We're not mind-readers. What you *want* it to do vs. what is is *actually* doing are best-told by your stated intent (provided) **and** the code to see where the two diverge. *Post the code*.

Comment: Not the real production code, but the [MCVE] with which you've been debugging this problem over the past few days.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the vectors outside of the loop, and clear them from within the loop. It could look something like the following:

```
vector<string> info;
do {
    // get input and do whatever
    info.clear();
} while (condition);
```

Some documentation http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/clear/

**Update:**

My original answer was specifically informing you how to clear the vector, but it seems like there is likely a better solution for you. Given your description there does not seem to be a need to move the declaration outside the loop and clear the vector at the end. Without additional code we have no way of knowing what caused the seg fault and how you should handle this issue properly.

Comment: Thank you. I will start here.

Comment: But why? Just declare `info` inside so it's scoped to the body. _Use the language_ instead of fighting it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yeah there is no need to do it this way given the description in the question, but this answers the question of how to clear the vectors. In this case you seem to have no reason to declare the vector outside of the loop and clear it at the end.